# How to prove that a number is irrational

Tags: irrational-numbers

We write all postive whole integers after the comma, how do we prove that this is an irrational number?
($0.1234567891011121314...$)

Comment: Does it ever end or repeat?

Comment: The given number is known better as Champernowne's Constant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant

Comment: Count of this sentence from wikipedia: "Irrational numbers are those real numbers that cannot be represented as terminating or repeating decimals.". So prove 'no repeating decimals'...

Comment: @r.pankevicius: that's not the usual *definition* though, so in practice you may or may not need more justification of that statement than "it's on Wikipedia" ;-) The proof that rational numbers have repeating or terminating decimal form isn't hard, and bears doing once. And you can consider terminating to be a special case of repeating: $0$-recurring.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The decimal expansion we were given is not ultimately periodic, for it has arbitrarily long sequences of $5$'s (or any other digit).

But any rational number has ultimately periodic decimal expansion.

Comment: You're right of course, but I note that $5/9$ also has "arbitrarily long sequences of 5s", so the "(or any other digit)" is critical, or some other qualification what we mean as a sufficient condition to prove non-recurrence ;-)