# Showing some decimal representations are not rational

Tags: recreational-mathematics, rationality-testing

I have solutions for the following two problems and I am hoping to obtain some feedback on my solutions.

Does the number $0.123456789101112l314\ldots$ which is obtained by writing successively all the integers, represent a rational number?

Does the number $0.011010100010100\ldots$ , where $a_n = 1$ if n is prime, 0
otherwise, represent a rational number?

Solution. My strategy for both problems is to show that there are arbitrarily long chains of zeros and so the decimal representation can not be periodic. Take chain of zeros to mean sandwiched between non-zero integers.

Problem 1. $10^n$ for $n={1,2,\ldots}$ will do

Problem 2. To show that a chain of zeros of length $n-1$ exists, consider $n!+2,n!+3,n!+4,\ldots,n!+(n-1),n!+n$ all of these numbers are composite. Now let $p_0$ be the largest prime less than $n!+2$ and $p_1$ be the smallest prime greater than $n!+2$. Hence, $p_1> n!+n$ and $p_1$ and $p_0$ are consecutive primes. As such, we can create an arbitrarily long chain of 0's.

What do you think?

PS: I didn't know what to say in the title, feel free to edit it

Comment: Your first example is the [Champernowne Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChampernowneConstant.html). It appears your first two examples are problems a) and b) from exercise 3.4.11 from "Problem-Solving Through Problems, Loren C. Larson" ([google books link](https://books.google.hr/books?id=PJ93BQAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PA22&lpg=RA1-PA22&dq=0.011010100010100...&source=bl&ots=P2Oogk5nON&sig=ACfU3U1lPSmvMdmt5Rp4xjbqw4DMpNH42Q&hl=hr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBqYvS7uXpAhXM66QKHcLtBCUQ6AEwAHoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=0.011010100010100...&f=false)).

Comment: @Vepir, Yes, are my solutions valid? I'm hoping to get some feedback on them

Comment: Yes. A proof for a) already exists on the site [How to prove that a number is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/935393/318073), and is a simple observation. A proof for b) is also a simple argument [I'm trying to find the longest consecutive set of composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2311654/318073) which you've already found :)